# What is the black stone in the Kaaba?

Tags: kaabah

I can not find very much reliable information about [black stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Stone). Why is it important, and does anyone know what it is made of?

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that the black stone was stolen in 931 and carried to Bahrain. When it was returned in 951, it was broken into several parts of which one is missing until today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of hadiths about the Black Stone.

**The Black Stone was sent down by Allah(SUBH) to this earth from Paradise.**

> It was narrated that Ibn ‘Abbaas said: The Messenger of Allaah  (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The Black Stone came down
>   from Paradise.” - *Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 877*.

**The Stone was whiter than milk, but the sins of the sons of Adam made it black.**

> It was narrated that Ibn ‘Abbaas said: The Messenger of Allaah  (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “When the Black Stone came
>   down from Paradise, it was whiter than milk, but the sins of the sons
>   of Adam made it black.”- *Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 877; Ahmad, 2792. Classed as saheeh by Ibn Khuzaymah, 4/219*.

(a)     Al-Mubaarakfoori said in al-Marqaah: This means, the sins of the sons of Adam who touched the stone, caused it to turn black. The hadeeth should be taken at face value, because there is no reason not to, either narrated in a report or by virtue of common sense.

(Tuhfat al-Ahwadhi, 3/525)

(b)    Al-Haafiz ibn Hajar said: Some heretics tried to criticize this hadeeth by saying: How come the sins of the mushrikeen turned it black and the worship of the people of Tawheed did not make it white?

I answer by quoting what Ibn Qutaybah said: If Allaah had willed, that would have happened. But Allaah has caused it to be the case that black usually changes other colours and its not itself changed, which is the opposite to what happens with white.

(c)     Al-Muhibb al-Tabari said: The fact that it is black is a lesson for those who have insight. If sins can have this effect on an inanimate rock, then the effect they have on the heart is greater.

See Fath al-Baari, 3/463

**The Black Stone will come forth on the Day of Resurrection and will testify in favour of those who touched it in truth.**

> It was narrated that Ibn ‘Abbaas said: The Messenger of Allaah  (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said concerning the Stone: “By
>   Allaah, Allaah will bring it forth on the Day of Resurrection, and it
>   will have two eyes with which it will see and a tongue with which it
>   will speak, and it will testify in favour of those who touched it in
>   sincerity.”- *Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 961; Ibn Maajah, 2944*

**Touching, kissing or pointing to the Black Stone** – this is the first thing to be done when starting Tawaaf, whether it is for Hajj or ‘Umrah, or voluntary Tawaaf.

> It was narrated from Jaabir ibn ‘Abd-Allaah (may Allaah be pleased 
>   with him) that when the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of
>   Allaah be upon him) came to Makkaah, he came to the Black Stone and
>   touched it, then he walked to the right of it and ran three times and
>   walked three times [around the Ka’bah].- *[Muslim, 1218](http://www.hadithcollection.com/fiqh-ussunnah/391-Fiqh-us%20Sunnah%20Section%2068.%20The%20Hajj%20Of%20The%20Prophet%20%28PBUH%29/21608-fiqh-us-sunnah-volume-005-hajj-and-umrah-fiqh-5019.html)*.

**The Prophet  (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) kissed the Black Stone, and his ummah followed his lead in doing so.**

> Umar r.a came near the Black Stone and kissed it and said "No doubt, I
>   know that you are a stone and can neither benefit anyone nor harm
>   anyone. Had I not seen Allah's Apostle kissing you I would not have
>   kissed you."- [Sahih Bukhari Volume 002, Book 026, Hadith Number 667.](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/59-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2026.%20Pilgrimmage%20%28Hajj%29/2145-sahih-bukhari-volume-002-book-026-hadith-number-667.html)

**If a person is unable to kiss the Stone, he should touch it with his hand or something else, then he can kiss the thing with which he touched it.**

> It was narrated that Naafi’ said: I saw Ibn ‘Umar touch the Stone with
>   his hand then he kissed his hand. I said, I have never ceased to do
>   this since I saw the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of
>   Allaah be upon him) do it.
>
> It was narrated that Abu Tufayl (may Allaah be pleased with him) said:
>   I saw the Messenger of Allaah  (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) performing Tawaaf around the House, touching the corner [where
>   the Stone is] with a crooked stick which he had with him, then kissing
>   the stick.    - *[Fiqh-us-Sunnah Volume 005, Hajj and 'Umrah, Fiqh 5.074B](http://www.hadithcollection.com/fiqh-ussunnah/399-fiqh-us-sunnah-section-76-tawaf-or-circumambulation-around-kabah/21687-fiqh-us-sunnah-volume-005-hajj-and-umrah-fiqh-5074b.html)*.

**If a person is unable to do the above, then he can point to it with his hand and say “Allaahu akbar”.**

> It was narrated that Ibn ‘Abbaas said: The Messenger of Allaah  (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) performed Tawaaf on his camel,
>   and every time he came to the corner [where the Stone is] he would
>   point to it and say “Allaahu akbar.”- [Sahih Bukhari Volume 002, Book 026, Hadith Number 682.](http://hadithcollection.com/about-hadith-books/59-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2026.%20Pilgrimmage%20%28Hajj%29/2130-sahih-bukhari-volume-002-book-026-hadith-number-682.html)

**Touching the Stone is one of the things by means of which Allaah expiates for sins**

> It was narrated that Ibn ‘Umar said: I heard the Messenger of Allaah 
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: “Touching them both
>   [the Black Stone and al-Rukn al-Yamani] is an expiation for sins.”- *Tirmidhi, 959*.

Answer (score 1):

The [Black Stone](http://www.umrahpackagesuk.co.uk/umrah-information/the-black-stone-hijr-e-aswad/) is blessed stone has many miracles associated with it; It floats on water and never get hot in High temperature.
Pertaining to its heavenly origin and its true color, Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said in one of His hadiths:
“The Black stone descended from paradise, and it was more white than milk, then it was blacked by this sins of the children of Adam.” (Tirmidhi)

Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said in one of His hadiths:
“By Allah! On the Day of Qiyaamah, Allah will present the Hajare Aswad in such a manner that it will have two eyes and a tongue to testify to the Imaan (faith) of all those who kissed it.” (Tirmidhi)

In another hadith, Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said:
“The Hajre Aswad and al-Maqam (Ibrahim) are the two jewels from the jewels of Paradise. Had Allah not concealed their radiance, they would illuminate everything between the East and the West.” (Tirmidhi)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
**[Hajr-e-Aswad](https://www.labbaikhajjumrah.co.uk/hajar-al-aswad-black-stone/)** is a sacred Islamic Stone which was sent from heaven by Allah. It is said that it was whiter than milk but the sins of Adam(AS) made it black. Muslims all around the world go to Kaaba and kiss or at least touch to black stone as a part of Hajj.